# How to transpile export default to module.exports

Tags: node.js, babeljs, commonjs

Is it possible to transpile `export default () => {}` to `module.exports = () => {}`?

Currently I'm using babel in a module, and commonjs in other, and when I require a file that is in the module that is using babel, in the software that is using common, I always have to call:

`myModule.default()`

That's really horrible.

P.S: I can't use Babel in the software that is using common.js.